# A exercise of recursively convergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

please can someone tell  me if the following recursive sequence is convergent, I tried to prove that the sequence is monotone and bounded to apply the Weierstrass theorem but have not been successful

$$a_1=1,\,\,\,\,a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+9}{a_{n-1}+1}\,\,\,\,\forall\,\,n\geq 2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** It's easier to prove something is convergent, if you can guess what it converges to.

Assuming that the sequence converges to $L$, we must have $L = \frac{L+9}{L+1}$, or that $L^2 = 9$. Since every terms is positive, the only possible limit is $L=3$.

**Hint:** $a_n-3$ = $\frac{ a_{n-1} + 9 } { a_{n-1}+1} -3 = \frac{ -2 (a_{n-1} -3) } { (a_{n-1}-3)+4}$.

Now consider the graph $f(x) = \frac{ -2x}{x+4}$ around $x=0$.

Can you use this to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |a_n - 3 | = 0$?

If yes, then this converges to 3. If no, then it doesn't converge.

Comment: Yes Calvin, but  as you prove that this sequence converges to zero?

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero I can prove something about the sequence. Look at the hint, that will suggest what you can do.